# accessing function attributes inside decorators

Tags: python, scope, python-decorators, function-object, function-attributes

Is it possible to access function attributes inside a decorator?
Consider below piece of code.

```
def deco(a):
    def wrap():
        print(a.status)
        a()
        print(a.status)



    return wrap


@deco
def fun1():
    fun1.status="bar"


fun1.status="foo"
fun1()
```

I expected the output  to be :

```
foo
bar
```

But I get the below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    fun1()
  File "D:\python_projects\test_suite\func_attribute.py", line 3, in wrap
    print(a.status)
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'status'
```

Is there any way to make this work since

```
def fun1():
    fun1.status="bar"


fun1.status="foo"

a=fun1

print(a.status)
a()
print(a.status)
```

Outputs:

```
foo
bar
```

As expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the decorator, the global name `fun1` is bound to the *decoration result*, so to the nested `wrap()` function object. Inside `wrap()` however,  `a` refers to the *original*, unwrapped function object.

So you have *two different function objects*, and each can have attributes; they are not the same objects.  `fun1.status` is a different attribute from `a.status`.

You can access the same object as `fun1` in the decorator as `wrap`:

```
print(wrap.status)
```

Demo:

```
>>> def deco(a):
...     def wrap():
...         print(wrap.status)
...         a()
...         print(wrap.status)
...     return wrap
...
>>> @deco
... def fun1():
...     fun1.status="bar"
...
>>> fun1.status="foo"
>>> fun1()
foo
bar
```

Comment: def deco(a):
     def wrap():
         print(fun1.status)
         a()
         print(fun1.status)
     return wrap

@deco
def fun1():
    fun1.status="bar"

fun1.status="foo"
fun1()

Comment: @SudhanNadar: yes, because then you are referencing the global `fun1` name that the decorator targeted. But now you are bound to that *one function you decorated*, you can't use the decorator on another function `fun2` and expect to get access to the attributes of that second function object when you call it. `wrap` will always be the right reference to the decoration result.